# Can i call two activities from one Service class?

Tags: android

all i have three activities right now.Ex. A,B,C.Activity A contains progress bar.Activity B contains image..and on image there one button if i click that button i want to call Activity C.
i got call to Activity B but i didn't got Activity C.So,i just want to know can i call two activities from one Service class.??

```
       @Override
public void onCreate() {

    //getProgressBar(dadaList);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Popup Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "popup");
    //Log.d(, "inc is");

    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), StopClass.class);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);

}
```

This is my code where i have called one activity from service class.
Thanks in Advance---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible. If I call first activity, and then the second activity, first activity will stop and second one will start.